# how to use oracle for jquery datatables server-side processing

Tags: php, jquery, oracle, datatables, server-side

I am using server side http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_oracle
but I have error like this.

[image]

how i fix it ?

Comment: go to your server_processing_php and take a look at those error lines

Comment: I just copy from this site http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_oracle, and edit field, table, and connection. I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: just look at those error lines and find the thing error told you

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5236/need-help-example-for-oracle-json-data-from-server-could-not-be-parsed   this is the same problem